# Are there any pre-built Javascripts for checking keyboard/mouse activity?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, keyboard-events, time-tracking, user-activity

I need a Javascript which monitors keyboard and mouse events to track how much time a user spends on the page. Specifically, actively using the page by typing, or moving/clicking with the mouse.

Thought I'd ask if anybody knows of something that might work for me to save some time. Otherwise, Javascript and Aspirin here I come... lol

Answer (score 1):

Example of recording mouse movement: http://pure.rednoize.com/movelogger/

- General information about detecting
  keystrokes:
  http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html
- General information about mouse
  events:
  http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_mouse.html

Comment: The first link is broken. I hope it will be replaced soon.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically all DOM elements can react on events like onClick, onMouseOver, onKeyPress etc. From a whole page down to each element. I would start that way, with any JavaScript library you like.